# How to know is class property is enabled or not

Tags: jquery, xhtml

i want to know whether the plupload_droptext class is enabled while runtime or not?
  and i want to perform some action if yes.

```
      $('#upload').click(function() {
            if( $('.plupload_droptext').enabled)
            {
                alert("Add files");
            }
        });
```

if any one know help me please.

Comment: What do you understand by an *enabled* class? Whether an element *has* class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to check whether #upload has the class .plupload_droptext or not.

```
 $('#upload').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('plupload_droptext'))
    {
    alert("Add files");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'enabled' but you could use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to see if the element you are clicking has a class linked to it -

```
  $('#upload').click(function() {
        if( $(this).hasClass('.plupload_droptext'))
        {
            alert("Add files");
        }
    });
```

Comment: + 1, 100% agreed, would answer exactly the same way.

Comment: Ya this is what i wanted to do. Thanks for ur reply

Comment: @Shivaraj - That's a pleasure, pleased my answer helped. You've accepted another answer - was that what you meant to do?